# Test to prove deals are not random

Tags: online, cheating

I played on a mobile app game engine that I suspect deals **non-random hands**.

I am looking for a method to prove it.  it needs to use a small number of samples since that game engine does not offer the option to export the hands.  Thus I would have to manually record each hand.

The deals are really absurd, thus I hope I can prove it with few hundreds of hands / 5 community cards.

The test might use only the 5 community cards / use only my hands / use the winning hand strength (I can record a game with friends where we see each river in order to not miss information).

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-random-generator

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, thanks, can you elaborate about this?  I don't think they use a pseudo-random generator.  I think they build extremely strong hands vs even stronger hands (coolers).

Comment: If they do not use a PRNG, what do they use? People in cryptography think about such questions in depth.

Comment: I don't know what they use, I think they cheat in a very obvious amateur manner.  However I looking for a way to prove it.

Comment: If they use a PRNG honestly but naively and you find the seed, then you can do the cheating! Have you thought of writing image processing software that automatically logs the cards being dealt by the app?

Comment: good idea, however I don't know how to do it

Comment: it would be a better to use your time studying poker and finding software that is trustworthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the flops are non-random so I will recorded flops and make a Test of Proportion, compare it to the random proportions as shown in this [table from 2+2](https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/25/probability/distribution-various-flop-textures-988998/)

```
[ FLOP TYPE ]            Calculated    Actual +-/100K +/-SDs  Calc /132600

[ Rainbow              ]  39.76471%  39.76471%     0   0.00  52*39*26
[ Monotone             ]   5.17647%   5.17647%     0   0.00  52*12*11
[ Two-suited           ]  55.05882%  55.05882%     0   0.00  (52*12*39)*3
[---check suit types---] 100.00000% 100.00000%   

[ Paired flop          ]  16.94118%  16.94118%     0   0.00  (52*3*48)*3
[ Triplet flop         ]   0.23529%   0.23529%     0   0.00  52*3*2
[ Unpaired flop        ]  82.82353%  82.82353%     0   0.00  52*48*44
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any knowledge of their code, it is very difficult to find out how their randomness is generated. It would take knowledge in cryptography and most likely a very large number of hands.

A method that anyone can use, however, is tracking it manually and looking for patterns. You can do this most easily by making a program that will gather the hand information. Worst case scenario would be manually logging all of the cards dealt over as many hands as you can and analyzing the data using statistics depending on what your concerns are.

In my opinion, this is a waste of time. Especially in the US, these mobile apps are not regulated and they have no incentive to make sure their randomness generators are truly random. If these apps use real money, they would have an incentive to not have true randomness because it will make them money if they run a shady business. Apps like the WSOP app that use play money have an incentive to make rare hands more likely because it generates excitement and action that players like to see.

No point in taking a lot of time to debunk these apps. Even if they are caught red handed, they will barely be affected. Their business will face no legal action and they will still find just as many suckers to deposit and play on their app. It is a better use of your time to find an app that you trust with a large player base, preferably regulated and legal with a good reputation.

Comment: Someone wants to bet with me on 10K that their deal is random.  It a good incentive to prove its not

Comment: @Cohensius ahh that is good incentive. Best thing you could do for the bet would be to write (or have someone else write) software to catch the cards for you. Depending on which site you are talking about this might already be available so poke around. Collect as many hands as you can and use statistics to show if it is random or not to a certain confidence level.